# How can I center data inside parent div?

Tags: css, html

I have a div that has text and images inside, it's 190px x 190px and I would like to have everything vertically centered.

I've tried looking on SO and Google and can't seem to find just a simple answer to do so.

What's the simplest way of doing this?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kGt54/9/)

HTML:

```
<div class="block">
   <h2>TITLE</h2><br/>
      <img src="...." width="190px"/>
         <p>Hello world</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.block {
    position:relative;
    width:190px;
    height:190px;
    background-color:FFF;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
    left:-10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding:10px;
    border:solid 1px #CCC;
    font-size:small;
}

.block p {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: If you want everything centered why are you aligning the text to the left in your paragraph?

Comment: @Paulie_D — the question says "vertically"

Comment: Vertical alignment is a real bitch in HTML.

Comment: Perhaps take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div

Comment: What browser compatibility does this need to be for, if it is ie8 and above, you can use `display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle`

Comment: @Pete I'm using chrome and this doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: You would also need to remove the `float:left` - you can't use `display:table` with `float` here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/kGt54/16/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can use this two properties:

```
.block {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

and remove the `float:left`. Review this demo **http://jsfiddle.net/kGt54/17/** and ask any question.

**Edit**

If you want to keep the `float:left` you need to make an external container who float and have the margin :

```
.blockC {
  float:left;
  margin:10px;
}
```

New Demo **http://jsfiddle.net/kGt54/29/**

Comment: Thank you. What is the "C" in `blockC` by the way? I've never seen anything like that before.

Comment: It's just to name it :P like block container just my way to do it

Comment: ohhh I see now, I didn't realise you had created a new container in the HTML :)

Answer (score -1):

```
.block {
        position:relative;
        background-color:FFF;
        margin:10px;
        float:left;
        left:-10px;
        text-align: center;
        padding:10px;
        border:solid 1px #CCC;
        font-size:small;
    }

    .block p {
        text-align: center;
    }
```

just remove the `width:190px;` and `height:190px;` in the `.block{}` and in `.blick p{}` just change the `text-align : left;` to `text-align : center;` i hope thats what you want to achieve.. happy coding.

Comment: I need vertical alignment, not horizontal.

Comment: What are you smoking?

Comment: yes you said vertically, vertical is from top to bottom.. thats what i did.. align everything centerd from top to bottom.

Comment: there is nothing in your code that suggests vertical align. You can't just remove the width and height, that's like "removing" the colour of text.

Comment: youre defining the width and height of your div to 190x190 then size of your image is 190x190, and you also have some text inside the div, the contents may overlap in the div so you should not define an exact width and height fot the div, if you remove the height and wodth, the div will scale itseft from whatever it has inside.

Comment: @GreenFox all you have done is horizontally aligned the text in the p tag and remove the fixed sizing of the block rather than aligning all the elements within it vertically.  I would have to agree with robotnik's comment of what are you smoking -also if you look at the image it is 190 x 60

Comment: i guess you didnt tried my code did you? the right answer and my code just did the same output. you can try it yourself.

Comment: I just did and all it did was reduce the size of the block and horizontally align the p tag - neither of which robotnik wanted

Comment: oh i get, my bad, i did not see the Fiddle link hahaha, by the way im smoking weed (just kidding).. you might wanna copy paste my code on a local editor, run it, and you'll understand me :)))